# Cannot connect to MySQL through phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, installation

I don't know what's going on. I've been trying to connect to MySQL through phpMyAdmin, but it's not working. 
This is how my config.inc.php file is set:

```
<?php

$i=0;
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = 'myPassword';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'config';
?>
```

Using the user name root, and my password, I can access MySQL through the terminal. However, when I try to log in through phpMyAdmin, I get the following error: Cannot connect: invalid settings.

Does anybody know how to get around this?

Comment: How did you install phpMyAdmin?  What web server are you using? What is the operating system? Is it part of a WAMP install?

Answer (score 0):

Try reordering the configuration so that the line below comes before user and password:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```

Answer (score 0):

My password was expired, so I updated it and now everything works again.